# Limited depth search in BGL without O(number_of_vertices) used memory or time?

Tags: c++, boost-graph

Is it possible to do a depth or breadth first search/visit up to some distance from a vertex in BGL without accessing, filtering, indexing, etc. all vertices in the graph?

The closest thing I've managed to write is (creates the graph 0<->1<->2<->3<->4<->5 but only visits vertices 0 to 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct custom_dfs_visitor : public boost::default_dfs_visitor {
    template < typename Vertex, typename Graph >
    void discover_vertex(const Vertex& v, const Graph& g) const {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Terminator {
    template<class Vertex, class Graph>
    bool operator()(const Vertex& v, const Graph& g) {
        return v > 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::vecS,
        boost::vecS,
        boost::undirectedS
    > Graph_T;

    Graph_T g(6);
    boost::add_edge(0, 1, g);
    boost::add_edge(1, 2, g);
    boost::add_edge(2, 3, g);
    boost::add_edge(3, 4, g);
    boost::add_edge(4, 5, g);

    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> color_map(boost::num_vertices(g));
    boost::depth_first_visit(
        g,
        boost::vertex(0, g),
        custom_dfs_visitor(),
        boost::make_iterator_property_map(
            color_map.begin(),
            boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g),
            color_map[0]
        ),
        Terminator()
    );

    return 0;
}
```

which does only print 0 1 2 3 instead of visiting all vertices, but the code still requires a color map as large as the whole graph (boost::num_vertices(g)). Is there a way to make the search complexity not be at all comparable to the total number of edges/vertices in the graph?

Using a bundled color would be acceptable because many searches would be done in different parts of the graph, but is it possible to reduce the complexity of each individual search in the same graph from O(number_of_vertices)?
Initial coloring of vertices will hopefully also stop when Terminator returns true but that seems to be taken care of already.
Maybe a related question: What about indexing if the graph uses something else than vecS? Can BFS/DFS do without indexing in that case?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using bundled properties is the easiest way to accomplish this. The fact that the color property is included in every vertex is better than creating the color property for each vertex every time a dfs is done. The graph type should be

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::undirectedS,
    property<vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type>
> Graph_T;
```

and the call to dfv is

```
depth_first_visit(
    g,
    vertex(0, g),
    custom_dfs_visitor(),
    get(vertex_color_t(), g),
    Terminator()
);
```

With the above, doing a limited dfs in a graph with 100 M vertices doesn't increase memory consumption (76.2 % of total memory) while with an external vector of colors memory usage increases from 76.2 % to 78.5 % while searching.